# How to seperate 3 sinusoidal signal of same frequency and phase but different amplitude?

Tags: continuous-signals

The wireless encrypted communication works as sending the message signal (sinosoidal) along with 2 dummy signals(sinosoidal) of same frequencies same phase
but different amplitudes(assume no interference among 3 signals), it is known that the message signal has highest amplitude as compared to other 2 signals.
Now we have to recover the message signal.how to find it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that there is no interference among the three signals? Are they sent via three independent channels?

Comment: As Jason R's answer says, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Can you clarify your question, please?

Comment: are the 3 sine waves separated in time?  Time division multiplexing?

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't make any sense. What you're proposing is:

$$
\begin{align}
x(t) &= x_1(t) + x_2(t) + x_3(t) \\
&=A_1 \cos(\omega t + \phi) + A_2 \cos(\omega t + \phi) + A_3 \cos(\omega t + \phi) \\
&= (A_1 + A_2 + A_3) \cos(\omega t + \phi)
\end{align}
$$

If the other sinusoids are truly at the same frequency and phase, there's nothing to separate; the result is just a sinusoid with increased amplitude at the same frequency and phase.